# How to disable selectableRow from an specific td PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a table with selectableRow, the selectableRow is being used to take the user to another view, what I'm trying to do is to disable the selectableRow for just one column, the one that has the checkbox, in order I can selected the row, but if I need to select the checkbox I can be able to do it without been taken to the another view.

```
 <p-table #tablaArticulosPendientesTif
    [value]="listaArticulosPendientesTif"
    responsiveLayout="scroll"
    dataKey="llaveTabla"
    [paginator]="true"
    scrollDirection="horizontal"
    styleClass="p-datatable-striped"
    [paginator]="true"
    [rows]="paginator.rows"
    [totalRecords]="paginator.totalRecords"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, 50]"
    [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
    currentPageReportTemplate="Mostrando del {first} al {last} de {totalRecords} registros"
    [lazy]="true"
    selectionMode="single"
    (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
    (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)">
  
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr class="fondoTablaPincipal">
          <th>{{'codigo' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'descripcion' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'almacen' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'tipotif' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'fechareferencia' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'diasrotacion' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'diasperiodico' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'numeromovimientos' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'contadormovimientos' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'nivelinventario' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'fechaultimotif' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'observacion' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'seleccionar' | translate}}</th>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
  
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-articulotif>
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="articulotif">
          <td>{{articulotif.codigoArticulo}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.nombreArticulo}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.nombreAlmacen}}</td>
          <td>{{listaTif[articulotif.tipoTif]}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.fechaReferencia | date: ('formatofecha' | translate)}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.diasRotacion}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.diasPeriodico}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.numeroMovimientos}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.contadorMovimientos}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.nivelInventario}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.fechaUltimoTif | date: ('formatofecha' | translate)}}</td>
          <td>{{articulotif.observacion}}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="field-checkbox">
              <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="articulotif.requieretif" [binary]="true"></p-checkbox>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

I tried to take out the checkbox column, with no success at all

Answer (score -1):

To disable selectableRow try to use `pSelectableRowDisabled`

```
<tr [pSelectableRow]="articulotif" [pSelectableRowDisabled]="your_disable_condition">
```

Comment: oh okay, but what I really want is to disable the selectableRow just for one row, the one with the checkbox (the last one)